# How to reference an Android action-bar tab text from another class in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, android-actionbar

I have set up action bar tabs in the on create class. However, I want to be able to create an if statement in another class to see if the tabs have text in them.

For example, in **onCreate** i have this code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenubar, menu);
    return true;
}

private void addTabs(ActionBar actionBar)
{
    ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("All");
    tab1.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
```

In a **separate class** but in the same code module I have:

```
 class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
    if(i==0) //I would like to include the tab text does not contain "" here.
    {
        fragment=new FragmentA();
    }
```